# How to mark all variables safe in Django Templates?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a lot of content that is generated by the admins of a site; I end up adding the "|safe}}" to almost every single template variable. This is annoying.

Can I automatically mark every variable safe, and instead opt to use escape when necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can be done by using Django templates' [autoescape](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#autoescape) to determine auto-escaping inside the block.

As outlined in the section *How to turn it off* on the [Django book Chapter 9](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter09/) (look for the text in the section *Automatic HTML Escaping*):

> If you don’t want data to be auto-escaped, on a per-site, per-template
>   level or per-variable level, you can turn it off in several ways.

This per-site way is to have a *base* template (the template all templates inherit from) which simply specifies `{% autoescape off %}` as the the top and `{% endautoescape %}` at the end of all your context blocks:

> The auto-escaping tag passes its effect on to templates that extend
>   the current one as well as templates included via the `include` tag,
>   just like all block tags.

As @ChrisPratt has commented:

> Never allow user-submitted content to be excluded from auto-escape.

Comment: Putting that into all my templates would not be very DRY. Isn't there some setting I can add to settings.py to turn off auto-escaping?

Comment: Actually, putting that into the content block of the base template would work.

Comment: Just be careful to never allow user-submitted content (comments, etc.) between those tags.